# Magento 2.1 Update Customer Custom EAV Attribute with REST API

Tags: rest, magento2

How do you update / add customer's EAV attribute using REST API?

I tried to do it using `[PUT] /V1/customers/{id}` with this URL

```
http://<website>/rest/V1/customers/1
```

And this as the body data:

```
$data = array(
    'customer' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'email' => 'email@domain.com', 
        'firstname' => 'John', 
        'lastname' => 'Doe', 
        'website_id' => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'attribute_code' => 'my_custom_attribute_code',
            'value' => 'my_custom_attribute_value'
        )
    )
);
```

I was able to edit the default attribute of the customer such as `firstname` and `lastname` but I have not been able to edit the EAV attribute.

Is it possible to do it with the default `customerCustomerRepositoryV1` interface?
If not, how do you extend so that it is possible to edit/add customer's EAV attribute?

Thank you.

Magento 2.1 Rest API Interface:
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger

Comment: what token should be used here ? customer token or admin token?

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the body data. I forgot to put the index on the `custom_attributes` array.

It should have been like this:

```
$data = array(
    'customer' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'email' => 'email@domain.com', 
        'firstname' => 'John', 
        'lastname' => 'Doe', 
        'website_id' => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'attribute_code' => 'my_custom_attribute_code',
                'value' => 'my_custom_attribute_value'
            )
        )
    )
);
```